# Downloading from Azure with Get-AzureStorageBlobContent - contents are garbled

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell

I am using this script to download the contents of a Azure Storage container:
http://bearprocess.com/2014/03/12/Download-All-Blobs-From-Container-Using-Powershell-In-Azure-Stroage/

```
$container_name = 'packageitems'
$destination_path = 'C:\pstest'
$connection_string = 'DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[REPLACEWITHACCOUNTNAME];AccountKey=[REPLACEWITHACCOUNTKEY]'

$storage_account = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString $connection_string

$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container_name -Context $storage_account

foreach ($blob in $blobs)
{
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $destination_path

    Get-AzureStorageBlobContent `
    -Container $container_name -Blob $blob.Name -Destination $destination_path `
    -Context $storage_account

}
```

Basically, it is working fine, I have all the files with their folder structure, as I'd expect.
But the problem is: The contents of the files are all garbled!
They look like this:

```
hE4P®dÊÐk–ŠO`‡Þ¿¯ýT¸J\NÝ:KëþÌ˜4¶êÎ›/µ¥Ñæ¨ŒöÑŠ'Œþ¼èÓ«@$;ðWc•óÖ
```

I guess I am missing something about encodings, but I cannot find any information about that.
The files I am downloading are html files, js files, and a few images.
I don't have a clue what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you please check if the files are compressed using GZIP compression while uploading? One way to test it would be to check the `Content-Encoding` property on the blob.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, you are totally correct, the files are GZIPed. Now I have to find a way to unzip them via Powershell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when the content returned is not what you can read. It can be an image, zipped file etc. Please check the content is readable on the blog and is not in the compressed format or any non-readable format.

**Update:** Noticed from the comments from  Gaurav that the issue is already resolved and it was indeed regarding content being compressed in GZIP format.